# Difference between endeavoring and endeavouring

Tags: difference

I thought the difference between endeavoring and endeavouring is just spelling like `color` and `colour`, but according to the this web page there is slight difference.

> Endeavoring is an alternative form of endeavouring. As verbs the
>   difference between endeavoring and endeavouring is that endeavoring is
>   while endeavouring is .  As nouns the difference between endeavoring
>   and endeavouring is that endeavoring is the act by which one endeavors
>   or strives; an attempt while endeavouring is .

http://www.wikidiff.com/endeavouring/endeavoring

I couldn't understand what is the difference. The explanation is too complicated for me. Can anyone help me to understand with a example?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-word-should-one-use-endeavour-or-endeavor

Comment: I think you are being confused by the inadequacies of the website, it is saying they are the same word (alternative form) with the same meanings, the site is just not repeating the definitions for the British spelling. This can be seen by the table comparison below where the British spelling is not filled in. Very unfortunate.

Comment: I didn't understand that explanation at all.  Looking at the website I can see it's automatically generated text, and as Peter says the table that it's generated from is incomplete.

Comment: Oxford dictionary shows that it is just a spelling difference. ([link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/endeavour)).

Comment: It is just a spelling difference between AmE and BrE, however the website generates comparison definitions automatically and one side is not filled in, the result is that gibberish text, even the OP is aware of different spellings, he's just confused by the text. I'm surprised this question hasn't been closed since there are plenty of more **real** questions that have been.

Comment: The web site you refer to appears to simply retrieve definitions of the two words and display them side by side. Ask it to compare, say, "English" and "British" and not only does it not give a clue to the real difference, but in fact spouts complete nonsene. ("As an adjective, British is typically British." Oh, thanks for clearing that up.) It cheerfully compares "cat" and "green" as if they were related in some way. I wouldn't take this site too seriously. Hopefully this is just the beta version.

Comment: Hey, this site is great fun though. Ask it to compare "cell" versus "mobile" and it says that a cell is where hermits live while a mobile is decorative moving sculpture. "Engine" vs "motor" and it talks about siege engines versus electrical motors. Try other simlar words. It's a hoot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no difference in meaning between endeavouring and endeavoring.

In fact, words that end in -our in British English end in -or in American English. For example, colour, neighbour, humour, etc. in British English are spelled as color, neighbor, humor, etc. in American English.

Answer (score 1):

Endeavoring (without the "u") is the way the word is spelled in the USA.

Endeavouring (with the "u") is the way the word is spelled in the the countries that speak British English (i.e. real English).

There are a number of such words such a color/colour, honor/honour and numerous more.